# How to tell excel that a number is a date in a custom date format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I have dates in the date format YYYYMMDD, e.g. 20230816 as of writing this question.
How can I tell excel that the number 20230816 is a date and not a number? Format cell - date does not work for me, as the list there doesn't include this date format.

Comment: Format cell would not work as the number is not correct for that date.  You will need to parse the number as a string to convert it to a date by splitting up the value and passing it through something like `=DATE()` in Excel Formulas or `DateSerial()` in vba.

Comment: Agree with @ScottCraner; for instance, type =DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2)) in an empty cell (assuming your text string is in A1)

Comment: just for your information the numeric value of today's date, 2023-08-16, for excel is: `45154`  It is the number of days (with a couple of caveats) since 1899-12-31

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't "tell excel the value is a date", but a slightly hacky way around this is to use Text To Columns.

1. Select the column with the date in
2. Click Text to Columns on the Data tab of the ribbon
3. Press Next on steps 1 and 2
4. On step 3 of 3, choose Date: YMD and click Finish

Your date will now show as 16/08/2023.

---

Alternatively, split the data using `=LEFT(A1,4)` in `B1`, `=RIGHT(A1,2)` in `C1`, `=MID(A1,5,2)` in `D1` and then concatenate it using `=DATE(B1,D1,C1)` in `E1`.

---

For either of the above methods, you can now format the cell and choose `Custom > YYYYMMDD`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner I've tweaked it to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this simple macro:

```
Sub ConvDate()
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Selection
        If Len(rng.Value) = 8 And IsNumeric(rng.Value) And Not IsDate(rng.Value) Then
            rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 5)
        End If
    Next rng
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Select the cell (cells) you want to convert and run this macro.